# Modeling for inclusion of two different entities

Tags: database-design, mongodb

### What I Have

I am currently hashing out the data model for an application that will utilize MongoDB. In my setup, users or `members` (as they are called in the schema) will be created and then assigned to teams (`team`).

Currently the set up is like so:

```
member:
    first_name
    last_name
    mi
team: 
    member (an array of objectIDs)
    assigned (the tasks the team is assigned to)
    name (string name for the team)
```

### The problem

In the midst of this, I realized I wanted the ability to combine multiple teams into one team. For example if I create a Team A and Team B but then realize they should work together on something, I would want to combine them as Team C and assign Team C the task.

#### Idea 1

My first idea was when the two teams were combined, that all the members from the combined teams would just be added together in one mass array of `member` ObjectIDs. I don't like that for several reasons.

1. It makes dropping members difficult. If I drop a member from Team A and want it to reflect into Team C, that's going to take a lot of extra effort to keep it consistent.
2. It also makes adding a member difficult. I add a member to Team B, thus I must add the member to Team C.
3. I'd imagine that would be a lot more taxing in terms of writes.

#### Idea 2

The best idea I can come up with at the moment is to add an `included_team` field to the `team` document. This will start to get a little verbose in terms of queries but it's the best I can think of so far.

There is a better way to do this. I know there is. Suggestions?

### A little Background

Perhaps this will help some understand if the solution seems all to simple to figure out. This project is my first endeavor into MongoDB and NoSQL. I come from an all SQL background for interacting with databases.

Comment: if you add Flag "IsTeam" on Member Object, it will give you way to identify if the member is a Actually leaf lever member or another Team. This way you do not need to expand all member of TeamA and TeamB before hand. "Team" can also be a member of another Team. When you need to access Member level properties then only you expand individual members of team. So when you add new member to TeamA you are not adding it to TeamC. Of course this makes Queries bit complex.